# knockout.js - Apply custom binding after components are bound

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I am using a custom `menu` binding for the jquery ui menu widget. Inside the HTML for my menu, I am using a component. It looks something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="menu: {...}">
    <!-- ko foreach: menuComponents -->
    <li>
        <div data-bind="component: $data"></div>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

My custom binding is using `applyBindingsToDescendents()` to resolve the bindings inside the `ul` before initializing the menu. This is a simplified version of my binding.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.menu = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);

        $(element).menu();

        return {controlsDescendantBindings: true};
    }
};
```

The problem is that components are loaded asynchronously. I am using a custom component loader, but I'm not sure if that matters. The side effect is that the `component` binding isn't resolved until the component is loaded. So the load order looks like this:

1. Menu binding initialization is started
2. Descendant bindings are applied by `applyBindingsToDescendents`
3. jQuery menu widget is initialized
4. Component is initialized and bound asynchronously

Since the component isn't initialized until after bindings are applied, my menu isn't rendering properly.

Is there any way I can force component descendant bindings to be applied synchronously? Or is there a way I can detect when they are applied and refresh the menu widget?

Comment: Not sure if it helps but the update to knockout 3.3 includes a synchronous option for component bindings

Comment: Are the <li>'s being created at design time or by using a foreach binding?

Comment: I'm using a foreach binding. I'll update my question in case that is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My working solution at the moment is to avoid the use of components completely. I simply use the template binding and apply the view models manually.

```
<ul data-bind="menu: {...}">
    <!-- ko foreach: menuItems -->
    <li>
        <div data-bind="template: {name: $data.template, data: $data.data}"></div>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

I tried using the synchronous option for my components, but the problem is that it does not *gurantee* synchronous operation. Another solution was to bind my menu in a `setTimeout` call, but I avoided this solution because it can potentially cause other issues. But that would have looked like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.menu = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $(element).menu();
        });

        return {controlsDescendantBindings: true};
    }
};
```